# Statistically testing for a significant difference between two slope values

Tags: trend, gradient

I have five trend lines plotted in excel of number of prescriptions of a 5 different drugs over time (MM/YYYY) and I want to test the statistical significance of the difference between the slopes, to prove that there is a difference between the trends of the data sets.

From the data there are two drug groups with much steeper trendlines showing a general increase in prescription over time, and the rest are flat (x = < 1).

Which stats test should I use?

Comment: Are you using linear regression?

Comment: What is $x$ and what are its units?

Comment: Yes I am using linear regression, and x is the steepness (y = mx + c) of the curve

Comment: $x$ is only the steepness if $m$ is the predictor. You can define any notation you like but if any notation is traditional in statistics it is response $y$, predictor $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the Wald test. Suppose that your estimated slopes are, respectively, $\hat{\alpha}_{1}$ and $\hat{\alpha}_{2}$. Then, you build a test such as
$$ H_{0} : \hat{\alpha}_{1} - \hat{\alpha}_{2} = 0$$
$$ H_{1} : \hat{\alpha}_{1} - \hat{\alpha}_{2} \neq 0,$$

with a test statistics

$$ \frac{(\hat{\alpha}_{1} - \hat{\alpha}_{2})^{2}}{VAR(\hat{\alpha}_{1})}$$

that follows the $\chi^{2}$ distribution with $1$ degree of freedom.

Comment: Does this work if variances of the two estimates are different? Is there a rule, say, to use the bigger one?

Comment: Note that many statistical people would be queasy about testing differences based on groups observed in the data. Testing whether steeper slopes are steeper than gentler slopes conflates evidence and hypothesis.

Comment: For this you are testing one steep slopes gradients (say 6.5x) against a less steep slopes gradient (i.e 1.6x), wherre the gradients are α^1 and α^2?